# Software for recurrence relations

Tags: math-software

What software do you use and would recommend for solving recurrence relations?

For example mathematica has `RSolve`:

$ a(n+1)-2 a(n) = 1$ for $a(n)$:

```
RSolve[a[n + 1] - 2 a[n] == 1, a[n], n]
-> a(n) = c 2^(n-1)+2^n-1
```

Are there any good (preferably open) alternatives?

Comment: As you say Mathematica has a built in function, but even though it's not open source, you can still program it, right?

Answer (score 1):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%2B1%29-2a%28n%29%3D1) does an okay job.

Comment: Indeed but you can not program it.